# Getting layer is not defined

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to create a menu layer, but I'm getting this error on Chrome console:

```
MenuLayer is not defined
```

But this is my menu.js which defines MenuLayer:

```
var MenuLayer = cc.LayerColor.extend({
    ctor : function(){
        //1. call super class's ctor function
        this._super();

        cc.associateWithNative( this, cc.LayerColor );

    },
    onEnter:function () {
        this._super();

        //2. get the singleton director
        var director = cc.Director.getInstance();
        //3. get the screen size of your game canvas
        var winsize = director.getWinSize();
        //4. calculate the center point
        var centerpos = cc.p(winsize.width / 2, winsize.height / 2);

        //5. create a background image and set it's position at the center of the screen
        //var spritebg = cc.Sprite.create(s_HelloBG);
        //spritebg.setPosition(centerpos);
        //this.addChild(spritebg);

        //6.create a menu and assign onPlay event callback to it
        cc.MenuItemFont.setFontSize(60);
        var menuItemPlay= cc.MenuItemSprite.create(
            cc.Sprite.create(s_start_n),
            cc.Sprite.create(s_start_s),
            this.onPlay, this);
        var menu = cc.Menu.create(menuItemPlay);
        menu.setPosition(centerpos);
        this.addChild(menu);
    },

    //this is the callback when the menu is clicked
    onPlay : function(){
        cc.log("==onplay clicked");
        var director = cc.Director.getInstance();
        director.replaceScene(new MainLayer());
    }
});

MenuLayer.create = function () {
    var sg = new MenuLayer();
    if (sg ) {
        return sg;
    }
    return null;
};

MenuLayer.scene = function () {
    var scene = cc.Scene.create();
    var layer = MenuLayer.create();
    scene.addChild(layer);
    return scene;
};
```

And this is my code where I refer to menu.js and the starter Scene, respectively:

```
    engineDir:'./Platform/HTML5/cocos2d/',
    appFiles:[
        './Src/resource.js',
        './Src/MainLayer.js',
        './Src/GameOver.js',
        './Src/main.js',
        './Src/menu.js'
    ]
```

---

```
var myApp = new cocos2dApp(MenuLayer.scene);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only answer i guess is that you need to empty caches.
(Chrome) Open "Developer Tools" -> "Options" -> "Disable Cache" and reload page without closing dev tools